# Compile for mac OS from windows using AIR possible?

Tags: flash, air

im developing an application on windows using flash, compiling in AIR 2.0. This compiler lets me create a .air app or .exe app. Is any way to compile also .app apps? Like the ones who runs on a mac? From windows of course. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Adobe article](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS789ea67d3e73a8b22388411123785d839c-8000.html), you can only create a .dmg (for MAC) when compiling on a MAC.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is actually very strange. You CAN compile .exe on Mac but from my experience these .exe don't work. So I could guess that publishing to .dmg from windows is actually possible but they might not work either.